# Merging two data frames, repeating the values of one to fill the other in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes in r like so:

```
df1 <- data.frame(tracks = rep(c(0:4), each=16), nodes = rep(c("nose", "eyeR", "eyeL", "head", "spine1", "spine2", "caudal", "tail"), length.out=80), coordinates = rep(c("x", "y"), length.out=80))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=4000, min=0, max=700), nrow=50))
```

Essentially df1 contains the labeling info of df2. I need an output df where I basically have a 4th column of df1 which is each of the columns of df2 stacked on top of each other, and the corresponding row label of df1 is repeated however many rows df2 has (in this case 50, but it's much larger in my own dataset). Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `rep()` function to create copies of the rows of `df1`, and then use `cbind()` to stick the two together. e.g.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(tracks = rep(c(0:4), each=16), nodes = rep(c("nose", "eyeR", "eyeL", "head", "spine1", "spine2", "caudal", "tail"), length.out=80), coordinates = rep(c("x", "y"), length.out=80))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=4000, min=0, max=700), nrow=50))
rep_df1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df1, rep, each = nrow(df2)))
cbind(rep_df1, df2)
```

This gives an output where the first few rows and columns look like this:

```r
   tracks nodes coordinates         V1        V2       V3        V4
1       0  nose           x  18.791475  89.43616 371.6074 272.61443
2       0  nose           x  50.063596 436.08428 209.1694  97.48476
3       0  nose           x 146.009226 582.71412 373.5483 470.81447
4       0  nose           x 435.155961 205.98816 628.5954 540.18555
5       0  nose           x  24.587971 480.34638 405.0276 158.46942
6       0  nose           x 246.314712 468.34386 227.4254 388.98637
7       0  nose           x 306.463035 269.85774 576.8909 507.84488
8       0  nose           x 544.223864 300.51239 474.8472  72.82660
```

You can then reshape the data further using e.g. `pivot_longer()` if you need to.